# Locating the node by value containing whitespaces using XPath

Tags: xpath, whitespace

I need to locate the node within an xml file by its value using XPath.
The problem araises when the node to find contains value with whitespaces inside.
F.e.:

```
<Root>
  <Child>value</Child>
  <Child>value with spaces</Child>
</Root>
```

I can not construct the XPath locating the second Child node.

Simple XPath /Root/Child perfectly works for both children, but /Root[Child=value with spaces] returns an empty collection.

I have already tried masking spaces with **%20**, **& #20;**, **& nbsp;** and using quotes and double quotes.

Still no luck.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Depending on your exact situation, there are different XPath expressions that will select the node**, whose value contains some whitespace.

First, let us recall that any one of these characters is "whitespace":

**`&#x09;`**  -- the Tab

**`&#xA;`**   -- newline

**`&#xD;`**   -- carriage return

**`' '`** or **`&#x20;`**  -- the space

If you know the exact value of the node, say it is "`Hello World`" with a space, then a most direct XPath expression:

**`/top/aChild[. = 'Hello World']`**

will select this node.

*The difficulties with specifying a value that contains whitespace, however, come from the fact that we see all whitespace characters just as ... well, whitespace* and don't know if a it is a group of spaces or a single tab.

**In [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) one may use [regular expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax) and they provide a simple and convenient solution**. Thus we can use an XPath 2.0 expression as the one below:

**`/*/aChild[matches(., "Hello\sWorld")]`**

to select any child of the top node, whose value is the string "Hello" followed by whitespace followed by the string "World". **Note** the use of the [**`matches()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function and of the "**`\s`**" pattern that matches whitespace.

**In [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)** a convenient test if a given string contains any whitespace characters is:

**`not(string-length(.)= stringlength(translate(., ' &#9;&#xA;&#xD;','')))`**

Here we use the [**`translate()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-translate) function to eliminate any of the four whitespace characters, and compare the length of the resulting string to that of the original string.

So, if in a text editor a node's value is displayed as

"Hello    World",

we can safely select this node with the XPath expression:

**`/*/aChild[translate(., ' &#9;&#xA;&#xD;','') = 'HelloWorld']`**

In many cases we can also use the XPath function [**`normalize-space()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-normalize-space), which from its string argument produces another string in which the groups of leading and trailing whitespace is cut, and every whitespace within the string is replaced by a single space.

In the above case, we will simply use the following XPath expression:

**`/*/aChild[normalize-space() = 'Hello World']`**

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev could you give one docs where such coding list can be found such as *&#x09; -- the Tab*.

Comment: @Babai, The whitespace characters are just these three: &#9;&#xA;&#xD;

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I am talking about any more for others .. Ok. Thanks for your prompt reply.. There is a very good [**`question`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513128/xpath-select-all-but-not-selfstrong-and-selfstrong-following-siblingtext). Can you please help OP.. I am trying but couldn't formulate.. Do you have time Sir ?

Comment: @Babai, Unfortunately I am quite busy these days. You need to look at the Unicode Standard (http://www.unicode.org/)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I tried this `concat(string(//textarea[@name="command"]/text()),'&#xA;')` but that doesn't happen, I got instead `1&#xA;`.. how to add a newline to a string using xpath ?

Comment: @Babai, You are adding a NL to the string value of the first node taken from the first argument of concat()  -- are you sure this is really what you want?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Actually I want to print the text from the respective nodes line-by-line.. This is the need..

Comment: is it possible to use normalize-space with contains? something like aChild[contains(normalize-space(),'Hello World')]

Comment: @AbtPst, Yes, this is perfectly legal and could have its own use cases.

Comment: but it does not seem to have any effect for me! does normalize-space() also deal with newlines?

Comment: @AbtPst, You may ask a question -- this is better than having comment dialogues.

Answer (score 10):

Try either this:

```
/Root/Child[normalize-space(text())=value without spaces]
```

or

```
/Root/Child[contains(text(),value without spaces)]
```

or (since it looks like your test value may be the issue)

```
/Root/Child[normalize-space(text())=normalize-space(value with spaces)]
```

Haven't actually executed any of these so the syntax may be wonky.

Comment: Dimitre Novatchev's answer is thorough but I submit it is overkill for the majority of situations. I am upvoting this answer because it is simpler and will work for most situations. Well, at least in spirit:-)--the function is normalize-space() rather than normalize(). See: official documentation on the [normalize-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) function.

Answer (score 2):

**Locating the Attribute by value containing whitespaces using XPath**

I have a input type element with value containing white space.

eg:

```
<input type="button"  value="Import&nbsp;Selected&nbsp;File">
```

I solved this by using this xpath expression.

```
//input[contains(@value,'Import') and contains(@value ,'Selected')and contains(@value ,'File')]
```

Hope this will help you guys.

Comment: Well, it will also match 'File Selected Import', which sometimes could be a trap and certainly was not desirable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

**"*x0020*"** worked for me on a jackrabbit based CQ5/AEM repository in which the property names had spaces. Below would work for a property "Record ID"-

```
[(jcr:contains(jcr:content/@Record_x0020_ID, 'test'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try #x20 ?

Answer (score 0):

i've googled this up like on the [second link](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@jackrabbit.apache.org/msg05777.html):

try to replace the space using "*x0020*"

this seems to work for the guy.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above solutions didn't really work for me.
However, there's a much simpler solution.

When you create the XMLDocument, make sure you set ***PreserveWhiteSpace*** property to true;

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmldoc.Load(xmlCollection);
```