# Reg expression to remove empty Tags (any of them)?

Tags: php, regex

I like to remove **any** empty html tag which is empty or containing spaces.

something like to get:

```
$string = "<b>text</b><b><span> </span></b><p>  <br/></p><b></b><font size='4'></font>";
```

to:

```
$string ="<b>text</b>=;
```

Comment: What about `<img>` tags, or other meaningful tags? What about `line1<br>line2`? What about empty `<td>` tags? Can you describe your purpose better - try to explain what you're trying to do, not how you think it should be done.

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to parse html with regular expressions. Use an xml parser instead

Comment: Also, I assume it should be `$string = "<b>text</b>";`, but that's probably just a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach with [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
// init the document
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);

// fetch all the wanted nodes
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xp->query('//*[not(node()) or normalize-space() = ""]') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

// output the cleaned markup
echo $dom->saveXml(
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)
);
```

This would output something like

```
<body><b>text</b></body>
```

XML documents require a root element, so there is no way to omit that. You can `str_replace` it though. The above can handle broken HTML.

If you want to selectively remove specific nodes, adjust the XPath query.

Also see

- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)
- [Locating the node by value containing whitespaces using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393840/locating-the-node-by-value-containing-whitespaces-using-xpath/394032#394032)

Answer (score 1):

```
function stripEmptyTags ($result)
{
    $regexps = array (
    '~<(\w+)\b[^\>]*>\s*</\\1>~',
    '~<\w+\s*/>~'
    );

    do
    {
        $string = $result;
        $result = preg_replace ($regexps, '', $string);
    }
    while ($result != $string);

    return $result;
}


$string = "<b>text</b><b><span> </span></b><p>  <br/></p><b></b><font size='4'></font>";
echo stripEmptyTags ($string);
```

Comment: this do the job. Just 1 more questions: 1) How can I tell the function which tags should be removed, let´s say I just need to remove: p, a and span tags.

Comment: After thoughtful consideration I really think you should use DOM approach instead as more reliable.

Comment: I changed part of your function to: (but now doesn´t work at all)
    $regexps = array (
    '~<(p|a|span)\b[^\>]*>\s*</\\1>~',
    '~<p|a|span\s*/>~'
    );

Comment: Related to realibility: in my case I will use your function just for text in some part of the html document, but I won´t use it for the whole html document. Then I think this won´t be a mayor problem. What do you think?

Comment: The problem with tag enumerated version is you never know what those tags will be.
Have '~<(p|a|span|b|font)\b[^\>]*>\s*</\\1>~',
for the first regexp.

Comment: You can try my version first. Should it suite you, stick with it.
Otherwise use DOM-version.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the code multiple times in order to do this only with regular expressions.

the regex that does this is:

```
/<(?:(\w+)(?: [^>]*)?`> *<\/$1>)|(?:<\w+(?: [^>]*)?\/>)/g
```

But for example on your string you have to run it at least twice. Once it will remove the `<br/>` and the second time will remove the remaining `<p> </p>`.