# Regular expression to match tags containing certain data

Tags: php, regex

I need help to make a reg exp. to match these:
The goal is to match any html tag that only `<br/>` or/and spaces.

```
<p><br/></p>
<h1><br/></h1>
<p><br/><br/></p>
<span><br/><br/></span>
<b><br/>   <br/>    </b>
<h2><br/>   <br/>    </h2>
```

Comment: What about: `<p> <br/> <!-- </p> --> </p>` ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: not similar to my question,That´s about self closed tags...

Comment: Had you read through 10 answers of bad jokes, common wisdom and malformed text, you'd actually find a useful answer. You're right though, it isn't very similar, but his one is: [Remove Empty Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721729/reg-expression-to-remove-empty-tags-any-of-them/4722152#4722152)

Comment: No I have not. And not, they are not similar neither. Let me know if  you see any empty tags in this question? Maybe your knowledge about php make you able to see both question as similar, but not mine. I really beg your pardon for my ignorance but your sarcasm is not funy nor clever.

Comment: @walter - the sarcasm is not addressed to you, on the contrary: the other link wasn't useful. As for the questions: they are very similar, in my opinion - the other question is looking for tags that have only spaces or `<br>` tags (they are *empty* in a sense of *not containing text nodes*)

Comment: ok,now I see your point. No hard feelings.

Comment: @walter the first linked question is usually supplied when someone tries to tell you that you should not use regular expressions to modify HTML. I wish people would stop throwing it at people because the accepted answer (while humorous) is wrong in that it assumes this to be an impossible task. Regex can parse HTML but it is difficult to do so reliably for anything but concrete snippets of HTML. For parsing arbitrary HTML, using a parser is most often the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
preg_match_all('#<([\S]+)[^>]*>(\s*|(<br\s*/>)*)*</\\1>#i', $html, $m);
```

If you want to strip elements that contain only comments as well as whitespace/`<br/>`, that's going to be a pain, maybe even impossible, using regex alone.

Comment: @walter, note that `\s`, besides tabs and spaces, also matches line breaks. If you don't want that, simply replace it with `[ \t]` to only match spaces and tabs.

Comment: Note that attribute values can contain a literal `>`.