# Remove empty XML elements with phpQuery

Tags: php, xml, phpquery

As mentioned in title, I'd like remove all empty elements from XML document.

By **empty** I mean elements that don't have any **text** nodes in it or in its children.

Is it possible to do that with phpQuery?

Comment: It is possible. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried with `filter($callback)`  but there is actually no documentation for it and I couldn't find out how it works in details.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: See [Reg Expression to remove empty tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721729/reg-expression-to-remove-empty-tags-any-of-them/4722152). There is answers showing how to do it with Regex and my own answer showing how to do it with DOM. The XPath should be reusable in PHPQuery.

Comment: Unfortunately your XPath query causes `Invalid expression` warning. But I tried whole your code getting DOMDocument from phpQuery first and it works fine.

Comment: @dragoste: Please compile an answer with your solution and show some example code in it how that is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Gordon's code from answer in this topic: [Reg expression to remove empty Tags (any of them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721729/reg-expression-to-remove-empty-tags-any-of-them/4722152)

Firstly I tried just to put his XPath query into `phpQueryObject::find()` method, but it gave me a warning saying it's incorrect query. Don't know why since it's using `DOMXPath` and should work.

Anyway the solution was still quite simple.

```
$pqDoc = phpquery::newDocument() // phpQueryObject created some way. Doesn't matter here.
$xp = new DOMXPath($pqDoc->getDOMDocument());
foreach($xp->query('//*[not(node()) or normalize-space() = ""]') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Now you have removed empty elements and you still can use your changed `phpQueryObject` since it has actually working on `DOMDocument`'s reference.