# Select whitespace node with XPath in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, xpathnavigator

I have the following code

```
var textReader = new StringReader("<root>    </root>");
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;
var reader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings);
var doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
var ws = nav.SelectSingleNode("/root/text()");
```

Note the whitespace in my root node.

`ws` is null. Why is that?

I could find examples where unwanted whitespace nodes crept up in a query's result but I could not find the other way around.

Thanks

Edit:
If my xml is

```
<root xml:space="preserve">    </root>
```

the query works fine. But in this case the node is of type SignificantWhitespace, not Whitespace.

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393840/locating-the-node-by-value-containing-whitespaces-using-xpath

Comment: @saravanan I just had a look. I am not in the same situation. If instead of using an xpath query, I move my navigator to element <root> and then MoveToFirstChild() just fails. The XPathDocument seems to be ignoring my whitespace node altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of those "Haha" moments...

XPathDocument has a constructor overload that takes an XmlSpace enum value. 
XPathDocument will ignore non-significant whitespace nodes if provided with no XmlSpace value or XmlSpace.Default 
To be able to select non-significant whitespace nodes, you need to pass XmlSpace.Preserve.

See : http://timoch.com/blog/2013/05/xpathdocument-and-whitespaces/

Comment: btw, feel free to accept your own answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan stackoverflow asks me to wait for a couple of days before I can do that