# XPath select all but not self::strong and self::strong/following-sibling::text()

Tags: python, xpath

So I have following example html to parse.

```
<div>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    Sub Editor at NEWS ABC

    <strong>Name:</strong>
    John

    <strong>Where:</strong>
    Everywhere

    <strong>When:</strong>
    Anytime

    <strong>Everything can go down there..</strong>

    Lorem Ipsum blah blah blah....
</div>
```

I want to extract this whole div except I don't want Title and Where and When heading with their following values.

I have tested following XPaths so far.

a) Without following sibling (1: don't work. 2: works)

```
1. //div/node()[not(strong[contains(text(), "Title")])]

2. //div/node()[not(self::strong and contains(text(), "Title"))]
```

a) With following sibling (1: don't work. 2: don't work)

```
1. //div/node()[not(strong[contains(text(), "Title")]) and not(strong[contains(text(), "Title")]/following-sibling::text())]

2. //div/node()[not(self::strong and contains(text(), "Title") and following-sibling::text())]
```

How to achieve what I am after?

Comment: Can you bit help me by saying what are the values you want to extract and what not.. It is not much clear...

Comment: I want to remove strong elements and their following text by saying if strong contains some text (for example Title).

Comment: `<strong>Name:</strong>
    John` also then need to remove -- right ?

Comment: May be or may be not. The idea is to write a selector that can remove any strong element providing their content.

Comment: Very Very good question indeed.. *+1*.. Although xpath can only select the nods as per the need,but can't remove anything...

Comment: lol I had almost hoped for you to solve this :)

Comment: I tried but some thing is a bit tricky in your need,which is to test if any immediate text node following  the `<strong>` tag... I can't formulate that... :(

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what parts you want: I understand you don't want "Title:" not "Sub Editor at NEWS ABC", and the same for following `<strong>` elements but you want everything starting from `<strong>Everything can go down there..</strong> Lorem Ipsum blah blah blah` onwards. Is that it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following meets what you are trying to do - it excludes the strong element containing title as well as the text node that is after it. You could expand it to include the other strong elements you want to exclude:

```
//div/node()[not(self::strong and contains(text(), "Title") or preceding-sibling::strong[1][contains(text(), "Title")])]
```

The strong node is skipped by the:

```
not(self::strong and contains(text(), "Title")
```

The following text is skipped by the:

```
preceding-sibling::strong[1][contains(text(), "Title")]
```

Note that the text node needs to check its closest preceding sibling (rather than its following sibling).

Comment: So what you're saying is that "remove all elements that contains given text in preceding sibling" That's nice! Will it also "only remove elements named strong"?

Comment: In the xpath here, it will remove the strong node with text "Title". Did I misread your requirements, did you want to remove all strong elements?

Comment: I wanted to remove strong and their following text.

Comment: Yes, this xpath does do that.

Comment: //div/node()[not(self::strong and contains(text(), "Title") or preceding-sibling::strong[1][contains(text(), "Title")])]