# Using XPATH to search text containing whitespace

Tags: xpath

In

```
<tr>
  <td class="f4 trimJustl"
      valign="middle"
      style="color:#ffffff;"
      artcolor="#ffffff">Create Network Container</td>
</tr>
```

I want to find the `td` element where the text is equal to *Create Network Container*.
I created the XPath

```
//td[text()='Create Network Container']
```

But it's not working. I also tried

```
//td[contains(text(),'Create Network Container')]
```

but this isn't working for me either.

Comment: I tried //td[contains(text(),'Network')] which works. But I want to use all three words in text i.e 'Create Network Container'

Comment: Given relevant portion of the HTML markup you're working with is exactly the same as posted here, your XPath should match that `<td>` element

Answer (score 34):

It works by cutting and pasting *your posted example*. Your original source *probably* has tabs or other whitespace characters that don't match. Here are some alternatives:

1) Normalize spaces

```
//td[normalize-space(text()) = 'Create Network Container']
```

2) Compare using string value of `td` (this will also match `Create <b>Network</b> Container`)

```
//td[normalize-space(.) = 'Create Network Container']
```

3) Check for each word separately (ignores word order)

```
//td[contains(text(), 'Create') and contains(text(), 'Network') and contains(text(), 'Container')]
```

4) Strip whitespace, tabs, newlines, line-feeds, carriage returns and compare result:

```
//td[translate(text(), "  &#13;&#10;&#09;&#xa;", "") = 'CreateNetworkContainer']
```

Comment: +1 Vote.  Was dealing with an xpath that I was using "contains" and it wasn't finding text on the screen when I had a hyphen.  The normalize-space helped me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393840/locating-the-node-by-value-containing-whitespaces-using-xpath):

```
//td[matches(text(), '\s*Create\s+Network\s+Container\s*')]
```

To be honest this works for me in several evaluators I checked it in:

```
 //td[text() = 'Create Network Container']
```

Previous try was to match all potential space-like characters that might be there (perhaps it's not just a single whitespace there and that's why this simpliest solution doesn't give you proper results.

Comment: Firepath itself not evaluating this xpath. it gives invalid xpath error

Comment: I fixed the initial query. It works, if you use xpath 2.0. Tested it here: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi