# Xpath Expression to match text correctly, but trim leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: selenium, xpath

I need an xpath expression for my selenium tests to get this element:

```
<td class="label">        Order Date      </td>
```

but not this one:

```
<td class="label">    Order Dates  </td>
```

I tried these two:

```
"//*[text() = 'Order Date']"
"//*[text()[contains(.,'Order Date')]]"
```

But the exact match expression doesn't take the whitespace into account, and the contains expression also targets the element with an `s`.

Comment: Did you need the xpath along with leading and trailing white spaces as it is in the HTML dom?

Comment: No, something that trims the whitespace.  I don't care about the leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Could you try this? "//*[contains(text(), 'Order Date')]"

Comment: `"//*[contains(text(), 'Order Date')]"` targeted the element containing `Order Dates`, which isn't what I wanted.

Comment: Just replace the string with your requirement. Hope this helps you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using XPATH to search text containing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362178/using-xpath-to-search-text-containing-whitespace)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to use the XPath's [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) as in `//td[normalize-space()="Order Date"]`

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: To be clear, it is also worth pointing out this fragment from documentation "The normalize-space function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, **replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space**, and returns the resulting string.". It is worth being careful about the **bold** fragment. This can be both useful and disturbing, depending on the situation.