# Cannot remove empty XML node using XPath expression @"//*[not(node())]"

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, nodes

I have the following node in my xml file :

```
<PERSON>
  <LEOKA_DATA> </LEOKA_DATA>
</PERSON>
```

I am not able to remove the LEOKA tag using the following code (snippet):

```
        string file = CommonVariables.MainDir + @"\Schemas\RemoveEmptyTags.xsl";
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDocument.Load(tempFile); //tempfile is the xml file

            XmlNodeList emptyElements = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(@"//*[not(node())]");

            if (emptyElements != null)

                for (int i = emptyElements.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    var parentNode = emptyElements[i].ParentNode;

                    if (parentNode != null)
                    {
                        if (emptyElements[i].Name != "LINE")
                            parentNode.RemoveChild(emptyElements[i]);
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        { **something here** }
```

However, the code above works if the node is like below (notice no space between start tag and end tag) :

```
<LEOKA></LEOKA>
```

I also tried using the following code but didn't work :

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(tempfile);

var emptyElements = from descendant in doc.Descendants()
                where string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(descendant.Value)
                select descendant;

emptyElements.Remove();
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locating the node by value containing whitespaces using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393840/locating-the-node-by-value-containing-whitespaces-using-xpath)

Comment: You are looking for a tag which contains whitespace, and whitespace can consist of numerous characters, like, '&#x09;' for tabs, or '&#xA;' for a newline, etc... So, even a simple space character, equals a value.  Thus, it won't find the node with the space character using not(node()).

Comment: Even if you use, string-length(text()), it won't work because the string will have a length of 1with a space char.

Comment: I suspect you haven't given us accurate criteria for what nodes you want to not select ("remove"). If you just want to exclude `<LEOKA_DATA>` elements, then your XPath is just `//*[not(self::LEOKA_DATA)]`. So what are your actual criteria - exclude all elements who don't have any child nodes other than whitespace-only text?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wanted to remove all LEOKA elements which have no child nodes and white space values. I got it to work using the following expression -->  [not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]

Comment: @JustinRusso - Thanks for giving insight. Your link to the possible duplicate issue helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your XPath expression as follows:

```
XmlNodeList emptyElements = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(@"//*[not(node()[
    not(self::text()[normalize-space() = ''])
  ])]");
```

In other words, exclude elements that have a child other than an empty text node, where "empty" means having no text value other than whitespace.