# Symfony DomCrawler link contains searched HTML

Tags: html, symfony, domcrawler

This is a project that I do in my free time to help reduce my time spent doing repetitive clicking in my company, so I hope it is not offending or prohibited.

[Page to be scraped](http://www.turck.de/en/search.php?q_simple=BI1-EH04-AP6X)

[image: Preview of the page]

I only want the URI of the second link, because it is the exact search match. The first one contains also the **-V1331** suffix.

Wrong:

```
<a href="http://pdb2.turck.de/en/DE/products/0000000000011ba40002003a">
    <strong> Product&nbsp;BI1-EH04-AP6X-V1331</strong> (HTML, 48.7K)<br>
    Product&nbsp;<strong>BI1-EH04-AP6X-V1331</strong> 
    Click to enlarge Inductive sensor Order number: &nbsp;4608440 Smooth barrel, Ø 4 mm Stainless steel, 1.4427 SO DC 3-wire, 10…30 VDC NO contact, PNP
</a>
```

Right:

```
<a href="http://pdb2.turck.de/en/DE/products/000000000001ecee0003003a">
    <strong> Product&nbsp;BI1-EH04-AP6X</strong> (HTML, 48.6K)<br>
    Product&nbsp;<strong>BI1-EH04-AP6X</strong> 
    Click to enlarge Inductive sensor Order number: &nbsp;4609540 Smooth barrel, Ø 4 mm Stainless steel, 1.4427 SO DC 3-wire, 10…30 VDC NO contact, PNP output
</a>
```

I have tried this:

```
$search = 'BI1-EH04-AP6X';
$crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'http://www.turck.de/en/search.php?q_simple=' . $search);
return $crawler->selectLink(' Product&nbsp;' . $search)->link()->getUri();
```

However, this obviously fails because there is a lot of HTML inside the `<a>` element, thus no link is matched.

Please do not be confused with Laravel's [Goutte facade](https://github.com/dweidner/laravel-goutte), it is the Symfony Dom Crawler method.

How to obtain the URI of the second link? Is there a method that matches a link, if it contains search HTML snippet (in our case `> Product&nbsp;BI1-EH04-AP6X<`) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by experimenting with the XPath helper extension and information from SO page mentioned below.

[Locating the node by value containing whitespaces using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393840/locating-the-node-by-value-containing-whitespaces-using-xpath)

```
$search = 'BI1-EH04-AP6X';
$crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'http://www.turck.de/en/search.php?q_simple=' . $search);
$crawler->filterXPath('//strong[normalize-space(text())="' . $search . '"]')->each(function ($node) {
print $node->parents()->link()->getUri()."\n";
});
```

It does need some more optimization, but for now it is allright.