# How to match HTML encoded text using xpath?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have an XPath like this. I am trying to do exact match a string in the HTML.

```
$d->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$txt="rest";
$txt=' '.$txt.' ';
$txt1=strtolower($txt);
$xpath->query('/html/body//text()['.
                           'contains('.
                              'translate(.,"'.strtoupper($txt).'","'.$txt1.'"),'.
                              '"'.$txt1.'")'.
                         ']'.'[not(ancestor::a)][not(ancestor::h2)][not(ancestor::h3)]');
```

It is working if the string is like this.
`"Please rest in ...."`
But if `&nbsp;` is present before **'rest'** in the string rather than whitespace then it is not working.
`"Please&nbsp;rest in ...."`

Comment: `&nbsp;` and ` ` are different characters. Code point 160 versus 32.

Comment: Is it possible to treat them the same somehow?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm no XPath expert. If memory serves me, XPath doesn't have a lot of string matching/manipulation capability. You may have to look beyond. Maybe use XPath to find *every* bit of text in the document, and regex to look for the occurrences of "rest" within those.

Comment: Actually, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393840/locating-the-node-by-value-containing-whitespaces-using-xpath for a better answer.